# Installing packages in R by using binary instead of source files: how to change the default

Tags: r

I just updated `R` and `RStudio` to the newest versions (R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02); RStudio Version 1.1.453) on my Macbook Pro last night. And, then I realized that when I try to install packages in RStudio, it installs from source code by compiling it.

I am using general fuction to install packages (i.e., `install.packages(XXXX)`). Also, I conformed that when I use `R` instead of `RStudio`, the `R` just installs packages by donwloading binary files.

I have to use `RStudio` but since it is compiling all packages from source codes, this is taking forever! I would really appreciate it if I could hear how can I have `RStudio` use binary files instead. Thank you for your help.

```
install.packages("lavaan")
```

> Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.5/site-library’ (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying
>   URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lavaan_0.6-1.tar.gz' Content
>   type 'application/x-gzip' length 684438 bytes (668 KB)
>   ================================================== downloaded 668 KB
>
> - installing *source* package ‘lavaan’ ...
>     ** package ‘lavaan’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>     ** R
>     ** data
>     *** moving datasets to lazyload DB
>     ** inst
>     ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
>     ** help
>     *** installing help indices
>     ** building package indices
>     ** testing if installed package can be loaded
> - DONE (lavaan)
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/private/var/folders/7m/_0cxbz8s02bdp4z7jxk3pky80000gn/T/Rtmp2ThASP/downloaded_packages’

Comment: From [`?install.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/utils/html/install.packages.html): *For a binary install from a repository, the function checks for the availability of a source package on the same repository, and reports if the source package has a later version, or is available but no binary version is.  This check can be suppressed by using `options(install.packages.check.source = "no")`*.

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce, @r2evans! I didn't know that! I tried and now I feel that installing a package takes less... But, it is still saying `installing *source* pakcage 'XXXX'`. I am not sure if I am actually using binary files or not. I added this output from `RStudio` on my question. Do you think I am using binary files? Thank you.

Comment: Huh, hadn't noticed, it is doing the same for me now. If you look at [`?options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/options.html) and search down for "binary", you'll find (among others) `pkgType`. I tried `options(pkgType="binary")` and now the installation of `lavaan` used the binary version (which was an older version than the source package).

Comment: Thank you for looking into it. Following you, I tried `options(pkgType="binary")`, it worked well.. in `R`; however, in `RStudio`, it says **Error in install.packages : type 'binary' is not supported on this platform**. I am wondering if `RStudio Version 1.1.453` is unstable version..? Or, maybe it has been like this but I may have not paid attention this much? lol

Comment: It seems RStudio is breaking expectations here. If you read the help, it also accepts `"mac.binary"`, have you tried this? Otherwise, you should submit a bug report to RStudio, they shouldn't be changing R's behavior like this.

Comment: Yes, I tried `"mac.binary"`, too. But, now provides an error that `unable to access index for repository https://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.5:
  cannot open URL 'https://mirror.its.sfu.ca/mirror/CRAN/bin/macosx/contrib/3.5/PACKAGES`. But, I am happy at least to hear that this is not happening only to me. I will check with another PC at work and see if it is the same case. And, if so, then, I will think about filing a bug report (with a bit hesitant since I have never file a bug report and as a non-native speaker of English). Thank you for your time, @r2evans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question was posted by myself a while ago, but today I randomly found out the potential reason why R  was installing packages from sources instead of binary.

I bought a MacBook Pro (2020) m1 apple silicon and tried to install R and RStudio. When I installed R and RStudio using brew, I realized that R tried to install R packages using sources instead of binaries again!

I spent several hours trying to figure this out and then, reinstalled R from `cask` instead of a Homebrew version! This seemed to solve the problem. Now all packages are installed from binaries.

```
brew install --cask r
```

I am not 100% if that was the best solution. However, I thought that this note might help whoever facing the same issue.

Comment: It is all explained in `installed.packages()` under argument `type` and then details. Two out of three OSs default to binary but _when there are no binaries sources will be used_.

Comment: This worked for me, but I am still confused about why R installed without the GUI (not from --cask) cannot find binaries but the cask version can.

Comment: I encountered the same issue with my Macbook Pro 2023, Sonoma 14.1 with R: stable 4.3.2 (bottled), RStudio 2023.09.1 Build 494. I re-installed the cask version of R using brew and was able to solve the problem. I still do not understand why...