# Can't install R packages, getting error '& was unexpected at this time.'

Tags: r, install.packages

I have a strange error which seems like it's not coming through R, but through powershell (at least based on the terminal-esque style). I just reinstalled R due to some issues, and it's been working alright. I installed the most recent R 4.2.2, then the most recent Rstudio, but then that Rstudio couldn't find my version of R even when I directed it to the folder. I gave in and uninstalled Rstudio and installed the version right before it. This seemed to work okay, until now when I'm trying to install packages (both through install.packages, and through devtools). It gives the error:

```
> install.packages('RSQLite')
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Ryan/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
        binary source needs_compilation
RSQLite 2.2.19 2.2.20              TRUE

installing the source package ‘RSQLite’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RSQLite_2.2.20.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3745301 bytes (3.6 MB)
downloaded 3.6 MB

& was unexpected at this time.
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RSQLite’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4uP1BH\downloaded_packages’
```

or it gives:

```
> devtools::install_github("r-dbi/RSQLite")
Downloading GitHub repo r-dbi/RSQLite@HEAD
── R CMD build ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   & was unexpected at this time.
Error: Failed to install 'RSQLite' from GitHub:
  ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed
```

I've previously installed packages on this R version and it just stopped working now. I'm no expert in R and I would appreciate any help or guidance. If you need any more information let me know and I'll update the post.

I'm running Windows 11.

Comment: Are you saying no to "Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel)"?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate [Rtools toolchain](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed to compile from source?

Comment: If you don't need the newest version (for which compilation from source apparently fails), you could try installing the slightly older binary version. See answers to this question, please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51289395/installing-packages-in-r-by-using-binary-instead-of-source-files-how-to-change

Comment: I normally hit Yes to allow it to compile, but I just tried the other options, and with No it seems to install some fine, but give nonzero exit status for others. Not sure why. I did install the Rtools for my version, but I guess it's not working. Perhaps it's not in PATH or something...

Comment: Does RSQLite now install?

Comment: I got that to install, but now I'm having a similar issue when trying to install 'biomaRt' through BiocManager::install. It seems that BiocParallel wants to update. The error messages are not really helping me.

Comment: `The downloaded binary packages are in
 C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcfTx6V\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘GenomeInfoDbData’ had non-zero exit status`
This is what happens when I run `BiocManager::install('GenomeInfoDbData')` (in order to resolve the biomaRt install issue). I said no to compile here and said to update all.

Comment: Not familiar with Bioc. My usually strategy when I hit these problems is to drill down through the dependencies till I find the failing package. I also update R, and update all installed packages, in case there are version issues.

Comment: That you were able to install RSQLite with no to compile suggest you may have an RTools issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with the DBI package. I am not sure why other packages were not affected, but it was due to an autorun registry entry from miniconda. The fix and path to registry item is documented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59480657/cmd-exe-throws-error-was-unexpected-at-this-time). I navigated to the autorun registry item in Registry editor. The command was obviously incorrect, it started with `if exist & if exist...` where the former command was incomplete and latter command was valid. I deleted the former command and the ampersand, which fixed the issue.

I confirm this was the issue by attempting to run [R.exe in git bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805173/why-cant-git-bash-run-my-executable) and I received the same error. That told me that the issue was not with RStudio or the package, but with the command processor.

This issue also presented itself as a problem with the binary vs source version of R, so I went down a rabbit hole of changing the CRAN repository, [as suggested here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/meaning-of-common-message-when-install-a-package-there-are-binary-versions-available-but-the-source-versions-are-later/2431). I also uninstalled old instances of R, but again I believe the issue was entirely due to the Autorun registry command.

I'm running windows 10.